# How to run mocha across entire app matching any files *.spec.js?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

I've tried the following:

`mocha $(find . -name *.spec.js')`

and

`mocha . -name *.spec.js --recursive`

However, I still get no matching files. Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
mocha "./**/*.spec.js"
```

(the -name flag belongs to the find command so isn't needed when not using find)

Also I think your variant with find should work as well, if you remove the single quote character at the end (but maybe that was just a mistake when writing the question):

```
mocha $(find . -name *.spec.js)
```

Comment: The last one worked! I must have missed that quote. Thank you!